# How to go from this equation to the equation of an hyperbola

Tags: graphing-functions, conic-sections

I've seen that $x*y=1$ graphs an hyperbola, but I am struggling to get that equation to the form $\frac{x^2}{a^2}-\frac{y^2}{b^2} = 1$. How can I do this? Ultimately, what I want is to be able to graph it by hand by looking at the equation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following fact: we say that an algebraic curve $f(x,y)=0$ is a blow-up of the algebraic curve $g(x,y)=0$ if $g(0,0)=0$ and $f(x,y)-g(x,y)$ is constant. Hence the hyperbola whose equation is $xy=1$ is a blow-up of the double line $xy=0$ (union of the line $x=0$ and the line $y=0$) while the hyperbola having equation $\frac{x^2}{a^2}-\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1$ is a blow-up of the double line $y=\pm\frac{b}{a}$. The double lines we got are just the asymptotes of our hyperbolas: in the first case, they are parallel to the coordinate axis, in the second one, they are not.

Anyway, by having the asymptotes and a point on we can graph any hyperbola.

Answer (score 2):

The formula $x^2/a^2 - y^2/b^2 = 1$ is for hyperbolas whose axes are aligned with the coordinate axes. $xy=1$ does not have this feature, so it doesn't fit that equation form.

See [this page](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RectangularHyperbola.html) for more details.

Comment: I think we need a suitable transformation here.

Comment: Well, rotating the coordinate system 45 degrees would make the hyperbola fit this form, but that doesn't really answer the question (as it doesn't actually fit the form in the original coordinate system).

Comment: Right. I really meant what @lab did.

Answer (score 0):

As the nature of a Curve is invariant under Rotation of axes

Using [Rotation of axes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_of_axes),  $ x=h\cos\theta-k\sin\theta,y=h\sin\theta+k\cos\theta$ on the Rectangular Hyperbola $$x^2-y^2=a^2,$$

$$(h^2-k^2)(\cos2\theta)-hk\sin2\theta=a^2$$

Set $\sin2\theta=\pm1$